# Mysql between code is not showing the correct output

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I have written a query to get the data between a particular month and year with another month and year.

For example I want to get data between **Nov 2014** to **Nov 2015**.

However, my query is just showing the output for just Nov 2014 and Nov 2015.

The data in between this two dates is not showing. Below is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM prc.tbictrepairsustainability 
WHERE sustainRegion = 'America' 
AND  (DATE_FORMAT(sustainDate, '%m %Y') BETWEEN '11 2014' AND  '11 2015')  ;
```

My **sustainDate** column data type is **date**.

Pls correct me if there is something wrong with my query.

Thanks

Comment: I think `DATE_FORMAT` can only be used in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the strings to dates in order to compare them to the date in the table.

```
SELECT *
FROM prc.tbictrepairsustainability 
WHERE sustainRegion = 'America' 
AND (sustainDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('30 11 2014','%d %m %Y')       
AND STR_TO_DATE('30 11 2015','%d %m %Y'))
```

Updated per Ronald's suggestion.

Comment: Don't make any conversion on search column, `(DATE_FORMAT(sustainDate, '%m %Y')` will create large amount of tmp file operation, `sustainDate Between STR_TO_DATE('01 11 2014','%d %m %Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('30 11 2015','%d %m %Y')` is best choice.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after i changed the date format to `'%d %m %Y'` with `STR_TO_DATE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM prc.tbictrepairsustainability 
WHERE sustainRegion = 'America' 
AND sustainDate Between STR_TO_DATE('01 11 2014','%d %m %Y')       
AND   STR_TO_DATE('30 11 2015','%d %m %Y')
```